# PHP создание свойст в изображении

Tags: php

Как в изображении пропписать свойства, допустим Автор: Вася

Короче, в винде при щелчке правой кнопкой мыши на изображении и выбора свойства, его можно редактировать.

Вот как такое сделать на PHP?

Answer (score 2):

? Странный вопрос) погуглить)

[iptcembed](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.iptcembed.php)

> iptcembed — Встраивание двоичных IPTC данных в JPEG изображение

Чуть ниже в комментариях есть класс для манипуляций этими данными.